# I have reinstalled Git on my computer . . . and can NOT add files to my new local .git repository

Tags: git, github

All my JavaScript/Node.js code is working locally on my Windows computer . . . and I wanted to deploy my application to Heroku via Github.

I installed Git, configured Git, added and comitted all my local files to my local .git repository in my local project folder. I also signed up for an account on GitHub, created my first remote repository in that account and pushed all my locally comitted files to GitHub. When I tried to deploy my application to Heroku via GitHub, the application did not show up in Google Chrome.

To fix this I DELETED 'Git' in C:\Program Files\Git.
I also DELETED my local '.git' repository in my local project folder and my  remote repository 'my-app' in my account on GitHub .
Then I reinstalled Git, configured name, email, default code editor and recreated the folder '.git' in my local project folder with the command 'git init'.

When I now try to add all my updated local files to my new, clean local '.git' repository with the command 'git add -A', I receive the error : 'my-app' does not have a commit checked out - adding files failed.

The 'my-app' is my old, remote repository on GitHub that I have DELETED.
I have created 1 new remote repository on GitHub with the name 'my-new-app'. Otherwise my account on GitHub is totally clean and updated.

Can you help ?

I am using the code editor 'Visual Studio Code' with a bash schell :

User@workstation00 MINGW64 ~/Project (master)
$ git add -A

.....
error: 'natours-app/' does not have a commit checked out -
fatal: adding files failed

Comment: Whats the output of git log and git status?

Comment: Thanks Wolfeius . . .

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: The output of the command 'git status' was 159 green files. They are now all committed to the local .git and pushed to the remote repository on GitHub. Everything is working !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Wolfeius . . . I have SOLVED the problem.

When I deleted the old local '.git' repository in my local project folder a NEW folder with the OLD '.git' inside it was automatically created. I did not notice that . . . so when I tried to add all my updated files to my new, fresh '.git' there were two (2) '.git's in my local project folder . . . and this resulted in the strange error message. :-)

Comment: I presumed it was duplicates.  Git status and git log help a lot.  Check the docs to see all the options for the log.  You can even see the commit tree in colors.